# Doctrine Symfony one-many not working but many-one is

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, many-to-one, behat

Ok, this is a real wood for the trees problem.

I’m trying to get a one-many to many-one Entity structure working.
I have three Entities

- Project (Has ID and Name)
- Researcher (Has ID and Name)
- Project Researcher (Has ID, Project Id, Researcher ID and Role of Researcher in this Project)

So they are coded as follows (Using Annotations)

```
namespace ons\Bundle\Geneapro\DataBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="gpt_project")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=" ResearcherProject", mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $researcherprojects;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->researcherprojects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add researcherprojects
     *
     * @param ResearcherProject $researcherprojects
     * @return Project
     */
    public function addResearcherproject(ResearcherProject $researcherprojects)
    {
        $this->researcherprojects[] = $researcherprojects;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove researcherprojects
     *
     * @param ResearcherProject $researcherprojects
     */
    public function removeResearcherproject(ResearcherProject $researcherprojects)
    {
        $this->researcherprojects->removeElement($researcherprojects);
    }

    /**
     * Get researcherprojects
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getResearcherprojects()
    {
        return $this->researcherprojects;
    }
}
```

Researcher is almost identical

```
namespace ons\Bundle\Geneapro\DataBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Researcher
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="gpt_researcher")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Researcher
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=" ResearcherProject", mappedBy="researcher")
     */
    private $researcherprojects;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->researcherprojects = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Researcher
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add researcherprojects
     *
     * @param ResearcherProject $researcherprojects
     * @return Researcher
     */
    public function addResearcherproject(ResearcherProject $researcherprojects)
    {
        $this->researcherprojects[] = $researcherprojects;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove researcherprojects
     *
     * @param ResearcherProject $researcherprojects
     */
    public function removeResearcherproject(ResearcherProject $researcherprojects)
    {
        $this->researcherprojects->removeElement($researcherprojects);
    }

    /**
     * Get researcherprojects
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getResearcherprojects()
    {
        return $this->researcherprojects;
    }
}
```

And Finally ResearcherProject

```
namespace ons\Bundle\Geneapro\DataBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ResearcherProject
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="gpt_researcher_project")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ResearcherProject
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Role", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Researcher
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Researcher", inversedBy="researcherprojects")
     */
    private $researcher;

    /**
     * @var Project
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="researcherprojects")
     */
    private $project;

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return ResearcherProject
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set researcher
     *
     * @param Researcher $researcher
     * @return ResearcherProject
     */
    public function setResearcher(Researcher $researcher = null)
    {
        $this->researcher = $researcher;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get researcher
     *
     * @return Researcher 
     */
    public function getResearcher()
    {
        return $this->researcher;
    }

    /**
     * Set project
     *
     * @param Project $project
     * @return ResearcherProject
     */
    public function setProject(Project $project = null)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get project
     *
     * @return Project 
     */
    public function getProject()
    {
        return $this->project;
    }
}
```

As expected that produces the following SQL

`CREATE TABLE gpt_project (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Description VARCHAR(255)             DEFAULT NULL, ClientData LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;`

`CREATE TABLE gpt_researcher (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;`

`CREATE TABLE gpt_researcher_project (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, researcher_id INT DEFAULT NULL, project_id INT DEFAULT NULL, Role VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_5E15A9AEC7533BDE (researcher_id), INDEX IDX_5E15A9AE166D1F9C (project_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;`

`ALTER TABLE gpt_researcher_project ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5E15A9AEC7533BDE FOREIGN KEY (researcher_id) REFERENCES gpt_researcher (id);`

`ALTER TABLE gpt_researcher_project ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5E15A9AE166D1F9C FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES gpt_project (id);`

So far so good, I’m now using Behat to write my scenarios, and I have the following Feature Defined.

```
Feature: ResearcherProject
  In order to track who did research
  As the Data Bundle
  I need to be able to create and manage ResearcherProjects

Background:
    Given there is no "ResearcherProject" in database
    And there is no "Project" in database
    And there is no "Researcher" in database

Scenario: A ResearcherProject joins Researchers to Projects
    When I create a Project "New Project"  
    And I create a Researcher "Researcher" 
    And I add Researcher "Researcher" to Project "New Project" as "Lead"    
    Then Researcher Project "1" joins "Researcher" to Project "New Project" as "Lead"    
    And Project "New Project" is Researched By "1" Researcher 
    And Researcher "Researcher" Researches "1" Project
```

The data is nicely loaded into the database and the test of a Researcher Project linking the Project to a Researcher in a Role works, BUT then the following occurs

```
01. Failed asserting that actual size 0 matches expected size 1. 
    In step `And Project "New Project" is Researched By "1" Researcher'.
```

The two functions doing the tests are

```
/**
 * @Then /^Researcher Project "([^"]*)" joins "([^"]*)" to Project "([^"]*)" as "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function researcherProjectJoinsToProjectAs($ResearcherProjectID, $ResearcherName, $ProjectName, $Role)
{
    $rp=$this->getEntityByID("ResearcherProject", $ResearcherProjectID);
    assertEquals($ResearcherProjectID, $rp->getID());
    assertEquals($ResearcherName,$rp->getResearcher()->getName());
    assertEquals($ProjectName,$rp->getProject()->getName());                
    assertEquals($Role,$rp->getRole());
}

/**
 * @Then /^Project "([^"]*)" is Researched By "([^"]*)" Researcher$/
 */
public function projectIsResearchedByResearcher($ProjectName, $expectedCount)
{        
    $project=$this->getEntityByName("Project", $ProjectName);
    assertCount($expectedCount*1, $project->getResearcherprojects());
}
```

`GetEntityByName` and `GetEntityByID` do what they say and work.

What have I done wrong, why can I work from the inside out but not from the outside in?
This has now been bugging me for two days so any help welcomed, I'm sure it's a real simple but it's beyond me.

**Edit**

So I think I can start to see the trees, however it is now a slightly different problem!
This was supposed to be a headless bundle so I hadn't provided any views or controllers. Having added a twig template, and run it up pops the links.

So it *must be* behaviour in the test that's causing it.

Comment: if the problem is only during the test it's more a problem of Behat isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
assertEquals($expectedCount*1, $project->getResearcherprojects());
```

This `$project->getResearcherprojects()` returns an ArrayCollection of `ResearcherProject`. If you want to count them you have to do:

```
assertEquals($expectedCount*1, $project->getResearcherprojects()->count());
```

Comment: That would be true if i was using assertEquals(), assertCount() does the 'counting' for you.

Comment: Corrected the answer for you. Pretty sure assertCount() expects an Array and not an ArrayCollection which implements Collection and Selectable.

Comment: Not sure what casting is happening behind the scenes, but `assertCount($expectedCount*1, $project->getResearcherprojects());` works perfecctly ***when*** the data is there, as stated in my answer. So making the changes you suggest would have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Having got the twig method to work I then wondered if it would work if I just pulled it from the database so I changed my scenario to

```
Feature: ResearcherProject
  In order to track who did research
  As the Data Bundle
  I need to be able to create and manage Researchers


Scenario: A ResearcherProject joins Researchers to Projects
    Then Researcher Project "1" joins "Researcher" to Project "New Project" as "Lead"    
    And Project "New Project" is Researched By "1" Researcher 
    And Researcher "Researcher" Researches "1" Project
```

And bingo it all passed so it makes it look like a caching problem. The Entity Manager is obviously returning it's catched versions of my Project and Researcher and they haven't been updated

so the problem is here...

```
/**
 * @Given /^I add Researcher "([^"]*)" to Project "([^"]*)" as "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iAddResearcherToProjectAs($ResearcherName, $ProjectName, $Role)
{

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();


    //Get Researcher
    $researcher=$em->getRepository('onsGeneaproDataBundle:Researcher')
                   ->findOneByName($ResearcherName);
    //Get Project
    $project=$em->getRepository('onsGeneaproDataBundle:Project')
                ->findOneByName($ProjectName);

    $researcherproject = new \ons\Bundle\Geneapro\DataBundle\Entity\ResearcherProject();
    $researcherproject->setRole($Role);
    $researcherproject->setProject($project);        
    $researcherproject->setResearcher($researcher);

//*** The following Two Lines make it work ***//
    $project->addResearcherproject($researcherproject);//Why dose this not happen automaticaly?
    $researcher->addResearcherproject($researcherproject);//Why dose this not happen automaticaly?
//*** ***//

    $em->persist($researcherproject);
    $em->flush();
}
```

If I do the reverse update and add the ResearcherProject to both Researcher and Project then all the tests pass.

But that begs the following questions

1. Why don't the Projecct and Researcher recive the updates?
2. or How can I force the Entity Manager to clear its cache after I have updated entities.